# Having trouble getting rid of display none inline style code

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting rid of a "display:none !important" inline style code on my website, I don't know how to get rid of it, it's causing the linked item to not show any image, or have an active link. If anyone could please give me any advice it'd be great.

I didn't write the display:none inline style, it automatically shows up when I upload the site to my web server. When I open my html/css pages locally it works fine.

[screenshot of list items 2nd imge in first row is where problem lies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f6zk.jpg)

[inspect element code screenshot from chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l5Gz.png)

Comment: This is completely useless, however, the `<a>` wrapping the image has a `class="print"` which MAY have something to do with the problem. What happens if you remove that class?

Comment: Have you got a link to the website so we can inspect the code?

Comment: Can't you edit it on the local css? or open your site's control panel and edit it there?

Comment: Your problem is with adblock. Some of their filters are too broad and block things they shoudn't. I see 4 images blocked there, `linkedin.png`, `twitter.png` `social.png`, `bbad.png`. Just rename them to something else and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have some sort of Javascript modifying the html, or possibly any number of other issues. If you could post the full code, it would be helpful in answering your question, and I could edit my answer to reflect something more helpful provided more information.

Comment: here's a link to my [website](stephaniebayides.com) not sure if this helps or not, wasn't quite sure how to comment in all my code. I don't usually code often but I've never had trouble with my site until now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in jQuery :

```
$('img').attr('style', '');
```